# With the NSA data snooping revelations, what can app developers do to prevent this?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

The recent revelations on NSA/GCHQ's snooping operations have been frightening. I believe as developers we have a responsibility to protect our users data. What steps can we take to prevent data theft, using methods like the ones described in this article: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jan/27/nsa-gchq-smartphone-app-angry-birds-personal-data

Comment: Don't store or transmit personally identifiable data without the users express consent.  Limit the permissions on your app to the lowest possible.  Many users are already savvy to this.  The most common reason that I don't install an app is because of the number of permissions it needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response Simon, however I'm looking to hear from developers about how we can tighten the security in our code to prevent this from happening. Although input from users on their considerations when installing apps is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guardian article, while nice, lacks specifics in the attacks. Hence, I would worry less about this specific article and focus more on how generally you can prevent "data theft", as you phrase it.

The #1 thing to do is use SSL for all your Web interactions, such as Web service calls. Use equivalent encryption options for other protocols as appropriate (e.g., TLS for email). This will go a long way towards protecting "data in motion". It is also something that is generally easy to implement. Consider adding in certificate pinning and similar techniques to help defend against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.

Here are four blog posts of mine from last year that go into more about SSL on Android:

- http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/03/04/ssl-android-basics.html
- http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/03/05/ssl-android-mitm.html
- http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/03/06/ssl-android-memorizing-pinning.html
- http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/03/07/ssl-android-onionkit.html

(though this material is a bit more up to date in [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android))

Equivalent advice is available for the other platforms you cite (I hope).

In terms of "data at rest" (stored on the device), consider offering encryption as an option to the user. As with SSL, the details of the techniques will vary by platform. [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) is a personal favorite, and it is available for most platforms, including the list from your tags. However, there are plenty of other options.

If you do offer encryption, make sure that the user has the option for supplying the passphrase, versus using some hard-coded passphrase or something derived from other on-device data. If the passphrase can be determined without human intervention, it is at risk of being discovered, or at least obtained automatically by an attacker.

Beyond that, I would recommend that you ask questions focused on techniques for a specific platform. "Shotgun" questions like this, with tags for a range of platforms, tend not to fare especially well here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your suggestions. It just so happens that the development I am currently involved in is android, so I found your answer very helpful. I have edited my questions tags to refine it to just android.

Comment: But don't a lot of these secure encryption protocols like SSL, have back doors in them, coded by the developers who made them in the first place?

Comment: @Dan: You are certainly welcome to provide links to evidence for your claims.

Comment: @CommonsWare But I don't know what links I can provide for this? How do I prove that the people who make encryption algorithms such as RSA, are actually paid by NSA to add back doors.The only thing I can think of is that I have watched some documentaries on YouTube about this. If you search for things like "rsa backdoor for nsa" on YouTube, you will see. Also check out other channels like "The Alex Jones Channel" - it also has some videos about the NSA.

Comment: @Dan: If you have concerns about specific encryption protocols and their security, ask on [the Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).